# How to communicate between an Activity and Service in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

We have two apps: My Android app that I developed and the Facebook app. Also, I  have an Android Service that is implemented inside my app, and it does the following: It keeps listening and once it receives a message from a client (i.e. Raspberry Pi 3), it goes to the Facebook app. This means we move from the Android Service to an Activity (i.e. the Facebook app).

Now my question is the following:
If I close the Facebook app (i.e. the Activity), I want the service that is running to show a toast message on my screen.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get any event of another app close. But in your service you can check regularly for the current running app by below code :

```
ActivityManager am =  (ActivityManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                    .getPackageName();
```

It requires permission also

```
Requires permission: android.permission.GET_TASKS
```

Comment: can you please clarify more? Do you refer to the Facebook app when you say  "the current running app" in  " But in your service you can check regularly for the current running app by below code "

Comment: can you please clarify more?